# How do I get Facebook User Basic info into FORM without login

Tags: forms, facebook-graph-api

I am using the Facebook Graph API to get basic info of a facebook user to prevent abuse. I want to get the profile pic, user id, link, and fullname. This form is for feedback. Any help would be great.

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>  
<script>
    window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
      FB.init({
        appId      : '290220450990670',
        status     : true, 
        cookie     : true,
        xfbml      : true
      });

      FB.api('/me', function(user) {
        if (user) {
          var name = document.getElementById('name');
          name.interHtml = user.name
        }
      });
    }; 

    (function(d){
       var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk'; if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
       js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
       js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
       d.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(js);
     }(document));

  </script>

  <div align="center">
      <form action="" method="POST" name="feedback">
          <input type="text" name="name" id="name"/>
          <input type="email" name="email"/>
          <textarea name="feedback"></textarea>
          <input type="submit" name="submit" value="send">
      </form>
```

UPDATES:
I have tried `<div id="name"></div>`, etc which does show the Profile Picture and Full Name. but I want it set as the value of the form data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`name.interHtml = user.name` should be `name.value = user.name`

Comment: Thank You. I can not rate but This is the exact answer. Could someone please up rate @JeffSherlock

Thanks Again Jeff.